# Passing Arguments to Main()

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to this and having a little trouble understanding how to pass arguments properly to the Main() sub in the code below. I've passed arguments before, but never using an array and I'm having trouble finding helpful search results. Would someone mind pointing me in the right direction please?

The link is a little easier to read.
https://github.com/freshdesk/fresh-samples/blob/master/vb.net_samples/CreateTicketWithAttachment.vb

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Namespace FreshdeskTest
Class CreateTicketWithAttachment

Private Const _APIKey As String = "Api_key"
Private Const _Url As String = "http://domain.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/tickets.json"

' verify if you have to use http or https for your account
Private Shared Sub writeCRLF(o As Stream)
  Dim crLf As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vbCr & vbLf)
  o.Write(crLf, 0, crLf.Length)
End Sub

Private Shared Sub writeBoundaryBytes(o As Stream, b As String)
   Dim d As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("--" & b & vbCr & vbLf)
   o.Write(d, 0, d.Length)
End Sub

Private Shared Sub writeContentDispositionFormDataHeader(o As Stream, name As String)
   Dim data As String = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""" & name & """" & vbCr & vbLf & vbCr & vbLf
   Dim b As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)
   o.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
End Sub

Private Shared Sub writeContentDispositionFileHeader(o As Stream, name As String, fileName As String, contentType As String)
   Dim data As String = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""" & name & """; filename=""" & fileName & """" & vbCr & vbLf
   data += "Content-Type: " & contentType & vbCr & vbLf & vbCr & vbLf
   Dim b As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)
   o.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
End Sub

Private Shared Sub writeString(o As Stream, data As String)
   Dim b As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)
   o.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
End Sub

Public Shared Sub Main(args As String())
   Console.WriteLine("Application starting...")
   ' Define boundary:
   Dim boundary As String = "----------------------------" & DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x")
   ' Web Request:
   Dim wr As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(_Url), HttpWebRequest)
   wr.Headers.Clear()
   ' Method and headers:
   wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & boundary
   wr.Method = "POST"
   wr.KeepAlive = True
' Basic auth:
   Dim login As String = _APIKey & ":X"
   Dim credentials As String = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(login))
   wr.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization) = "Basic " & credentials

' Body:
   Using rs As Stream = wr.GetRequestStream()

' Email:
   writeBoundaryBytes(rs, boundary)
   writeContentDispositionFormDataHeader(rs, "helpdesk_ticket[email]")
   writeString(rs, "example@example.com")
   writeCRLF(rs)

' Subject:
   writeBoundaryBytes(rs, boundary)
   writeContentDispositionFormDataHeader(rs, "helpdesk_ticket[subject]")
   writeString(rs, "Ticket Title")
   writeCRLF(rs)

' Description:
   writeBoundaryBytes(rs, boundary)
   writeContentDispositionFormDataHeader(rs, "helpdesk_ticket[description]")
   writeString(rs, "Ticket description.")
   writeCRLF(rs)

' Attachment:
   writeBoundaryBytes(rs, boundary)
   writeContentDispositionFileHeader(rs, "helpdesk_ticket[attachments][][resource]", "x.txt", "text/plain")
   Dim fs As New FileStream("x.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
   Dim data As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}
   fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
   fs.Close()
   rs.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
   writeCRLF(rs)

' End marker:
  writeBoundaryBytes(rs, boundary)
   rs.Close()
End Using

' Response processing:
Try
   Console.WriteLine("Submitting Request")
   Dim response = DirectCast(wr.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
   Dim resStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
   Dim resJson As String = New StreamReader(resStream, Encoding.ASCII).ReadToEnd()
   Console.WriteLine(resJson)
Catch ex As Exception
   Console.WriteLine("ERROR")
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
Finally
   Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine)
   Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine)
End Try
End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Sub Main is the app's startup procedure.  The args there are those entered on the commandline (e.g. `myapp /GoFast /Task=6`).  You dont call it and you dont pass anything to it

Comment: if you mean to specify those startup params when debugging, **Project -> Properties -> Compile** enter the desired command line into "Command Line Arguments"

Comment: Ok I see. So this is meant to be a standalone console application? That's not what I was looking for. I'll see if I can pull any useful information out of it and try to reuse it inside my application. Thanks.

Comment: Not just for Console Apps - winform apps can take command line args too

Comment: To answer your other question, yes, this is a console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this code is inside a class and not a module, `Main` would not be considered a startup point to your application. Although, the code is very reminiscent of a startup point. Maybe you copied it from somewhere?

To answer the question on how to pass an array, you first need to create an array to pass to it.

```
Dim x(2) as string 'This creates 3 items in the array, 0 based
x(0) = "Test1"
x(1) = "Test2"
x(2) = "Test3"
```

Then, since this is in a class, you must have an instance of your class:

```
dim MyClass as new CreateTicketWithAttachment
```

Then call the sub

```
MyClass.Main(x)
```